# Redondear las esquinas de un View en Kotlin

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

Tengo este *View* en Kotlin:

```
<View
    android:id="@+id/DotView"
    android:layout_width="6.5dp"
    android:layout_height="6.5dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    />
```

y necesito redondearle las esquinas ya que es un *Dot* y he estado investigando y probando de cómo puedo hacerle para redondearle las esquinas pero nada más no doy con la respuesta.

Como le puedo hacer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Crear un archivo border_radius.xml en drawable / New resources Drawable.

2) Añadir un recurso shape y modificar el radius a necesidad.

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimary" />

    <corners android:radius="9dp" />
</shape>
```

3) Añadir a tu nuevo estilo como background.

```
<View
android:id="@+id/DotView"
android:layout_width="6.5dp"
android:layout_height="6.5dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
android:background="@drawable/border_radius"
/>
```

Comment: me funcionó, gracias!